# For as a coordinate connector

Tags: conjunctions, syntactic-analysis

[image]

In this sentence "for" is used as coordinate connector, so therefore, both before and after "for" should be a complete clause right?

"Despite its small size and slow gait, the wolverine is an effective predator"
is normal.

"What it lacks in speed and size it makes up in strength and endurance."
I'm confused with this one. It seems to have 2 subjects.

Or when we use the connector "for" we should add another noun as an object for it? Quite confusing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there are two subjects. The structure is quite complex, as the subordinate clause is what is called a [pseudo-cleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence#Types), with a relative clause embedded in it.

So

> It makes up (for) *something* by strength and endurance

Fronting the object for emphasis. (Myself, I would retain the *for*, but not everybody would).

> *something* it makes up (for) by strength and endurance

But the *something* is the relative clause *what it lacks in speed and size*:

> [What it lacks in speed and size] it makes up (for) by strength and endurance.

Then embed the whole thing using the subordinating conjunction *for*:

> Despite its small size and slow gait, the wolverine is an effective predator, for [ [What it lacks in speed and size] it makes up (for) by strength and endurance].

Comment: Though I'd call that "relative clause" an "embedded question complement clause", simply because it functions as a subject. There's no formal structural or semantic distinction, though.

Comment: So therefore, "Despite its small size and slow gait, the wolverine is an effective predator, for What it lacks in speed and size] it makes up _for_ by strength and endurance." is also correct ?

Comment: @user2860952: Yes, that is what I would write. To me, the phrasal verb in question is _make up for_, not _make up_ (which has different meanings).